# Не работает под меню Bootstrap из под мобильных устроиств

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

На сайте есть под меню, первый уровень кликается, а второе и третье подменю не нажимается, можете подсказать почему на [этом сайте](http://bio-ritm.kz)?

Comment: выделите проблему, сделайте fiddle.

Comment: @gold дайте код вашего меню. Именно html-код. Залейте его на [Ideone](http://ideone.com/).

Comment: @eicto,@intro94 Впринципе дал ссылку на сайт ) проблему разрешилась, ответ внизу, спасибо )

Comment: @gold у меня не грузится сайт твой. Скорость инета низкая. Но прикол в том, что я тоже до этого додумался. Только хотел отписать, смотрю - опоздал немного. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо ребята, нашел решение, работает, уже проверил:

В файле bootstrap.js найти строку `ontouchstart` и поменять ее на `disable-ontouchstart`.

Почему не работает 2-ой уровень? Потому что первый уровень выходит по клику, а второй по `:hover`, нужно делать 'хитрый' клик, либо ставить костыль, чтобы на мобиле меню выпадало по клику ;)

Comment: @gold а где инфу нарыл? Я еле додумался до этого, а в нете найти не мог. Можешь привести свой кусок кода со строкой `ontouchstart`?

Comment: Погодь, так у тебя 2 версия!

Comment: @intro94 Сорри, да у меня 2-я версия ) в 3-ей версий вроде тоже самое `if (!isActive) {
        if ('disable-ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
          // if mobile we we use a backdrop because click events don't delegate
          $('<div class="dropdown-backdrop"/>').insertBefore($(this)).on('click', clearMenus)
        }
        $parent.toggleClass('open')
      }`

Comment: @intro94  На 3-м надо испытание сделать и проверить, как раз есть верстка одного сайта на 3-м Bootstrap-e

Comment: @gold в том-то и дело, что в 3 версии отличается. Я уже успел скачать твой скрипт. У меня в конструкции `if (!isActive) {}` намного больше кода. И в третьей версии убрано Выпадающее подменю `.dropdown-submenu`. Почитай это: [русский оф. сайт](http://www.oneskyapp.com/docs/bootstrap/ru/getting-started#migration). Я дал ссылку как раз на список изменений. Такая вот загогулина. :)

Comment: @intro94 посмотрю, поразбираюсь)

Answer (score 0):

в 3-м бутстрапе подменю вообще не открывается из-за того, что нет скроллинга.

во всяком случае, так на андроиде.

Comment: @fdjgfjfgdj не согласен. Первый уровень открывается. Скроллинг есть. 

@gold Подозреваю, что второй уровень не открывается из-за JS. Когда на него нажимаешь - закрывается первый. Вызывается та же функция, что работает с первым уровнем. Надо JS-файл курить. Видимо разработчики Бутстрапа не учитывали, что могут быть вторые уровни. :)

Comment: @intro94 надо по моему курить мануалы)

Answer (score 0):

В версии Bootstap 5

Вместо:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
```

использовал (изменил data-toggle и data-target на data-bs-toggle и data-bs-target соответственно):

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
```